# Load information about feature for Geojson

Tags: geojson, vector-layer

Is it possible to display whole "info" for vector layer? I have a lot of geojsons with different feature in one map. I would like to show information.WMS can display info in this case (image). How I should do this for geojson?[image]

Comment: Do you mean info from one clicked feature or from the whole layer? WFS can be used for both cases. Example about reading the whole layer as GeoJSON: http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&version=1.0.0&service=wfs&typename=topp:states&outputformat=json

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be showing a WMS GetMap response for a point data source, and a corresponding WMS GetFeatureInfo response for some point on that map.

If you want to access the data as GeoJSON you will need to use a WFS (provides vector data) and not a WMS (provides image data).

Your example looks to come from ArcGIS, but I don't think that ArcGIS can be configured to give a GeoJSON WFS response.  I think both MapServer and GeoServer are possibilities.